# How to reuse the paginationControl partial while passing different parameters to each instance

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I'm using the paginationControl partial, and passing parameters through the 4th parameter to allow me to paginate "filtered" results. That's working fine, but I'd like to be able to use the same partial for all instances of pagination even though they'll use different parameters.

e.g. "properties" are filtered by no. bedrooms

giving a 4th paramater in the instance of the pagination control in the view script of...

```
array('beds' => '$beds')
```

and used in the partial...

```
$this->beds
```

whereas "clients" are filtered by location

giving a 4th paramater in the instance of the pagination control in the view script of...

```
array('location' => '$location')
```

and used in the partial...

```
$this->location
```

How to best accomplish this? I could access the 4th parameter as an array of keys and values, and loop over the array and build the arguments for the url view helper within the paginationControl partial IF I could work out how to access the array. But but perhaps that's not the approach to take anyway..

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here's the partial I'm using to output the pagination controls as requested in the comments.

```
    <div class="pagination">
      <div class="pages">

          <!-- First page link -->
             <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
                <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array('group_id' => $this->group_id, 'page' => $this->first)); ?>">Start</a>
          <?php else: ?>
                  <span class="disabled">Start</span>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <!-- Previous page link -->
          <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
                <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array('group_id' => $this->group_id, 'page' => $this->previous)); ?>">Previous</a>
          <?php else: ?>
              <span class="disabled">Previous</span>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <!-- Numbered page links -->

          <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
              <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
                  <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array('group_id' => $this->group_id, 'page' => $page)); ?>"><?= $page; ?></a>
              <?php else: ?>
                  <span class="current"><?= $page; ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          <!-- Next page link -->
          <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
                <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array('group_id' => $this->group_id, 'page' => $this->next)); ?>">Next</a>
          <?php else: ?>
               <span class="disabled">Next</span>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <!-- Last page link -->
          <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
                <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array('group_id' => $this->group_id, 'page' => $this->last)); ?>">End</a>
          <?php else: ?>
              <span class="disabled">End</span>
          <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I have accepted RockyFords solution because it answers the basic question of accessing the parameters passed through the 4th parameter in the instantiation of the pagination controls partial. However, I include my complete fina partial here in case another reader wants the resultant parameters to generate a query string.

```
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="pages">
 <?php 
   $params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
   unset($params['controller']);
   unset($params['action']);
 ?>


  <?= $this->first ?> 
  <!-- First page link -->
  <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array_merge($params , array('page' => $this->first))); ?>">Start</a>
  <?php else: ?>
        <span class="disabled">Start</span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <!-- Previous page link -->
  <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array_merge($params , array('page' => $this->previous))); ?>">Previous</a>
  <?php else: ?>
       <span class="disabled">Previous</span>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <!-- Numbered page links -->

  <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
      <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
          <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array_merge($params , array('page' => $page))); ?>"><?= $page; ?></a>
      <?php else: ?>
          <span class="current"><?= $page; ?></span>
      <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  <!-- Next page link -->
  <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array_merge($params , array('page' => $this->next))); ?>">Next</a>
  <?php else: ?>
       <span class="disabled">Next</span>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <!-- Last page link -->
  <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url() . "?" . http_build_query(array_merge($params , array('page' => $this->last))); ?>">End</a>
  <?php else: ?>
      <span class="disabled">End</span>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the partial. It's difficult to offer help without understand the implementation.

Comment: The partial is basically straight out of the Zend manual, but I'll include it anyway.

Comment: I found an error :) your first if() statement for the 'Start' Link should probably check `isset($this->first)` instead of `isset($this->previous)`

Comment: Is the group_id parameter the one that causing you issues? Is that your 4th param?

Comment: @RockyFord re: error, I just consulted the manual and tested, and $this->first and $this->last return the page number. This code relies on the $this->previous and $this->next going undefined when no previous or next page exists. I could change it to if($this->previous!=$this->current) i suppose, but on balanace I think it's more understandable as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it...

Try something like:

```
<?php
if ($this->pageCount) :
    //you need to add each of the request parameters to url
    $params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                    ->getRequest()->getParams();
    //remove the system parameters, $this->url will put them back
    unset($params['module']);
    unset($params['controller']);
    unset($params['action']);
    ?>
    <div class="paginationControl">         
                    <!--First Page Link -->
                    <?php if (isset($this->first)): ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->first)))
                        ?>">
                            &lt; First</a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="disabled">&lt; First</span>
                    <?php endif ?>

                    <!--Previous Page Links-->
                    <?php if (isset($this->previous)) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php
                echo $this->url(array_merge($params, array('page' => $this->previous)))
                        ?>">
                            &lt; Prev</a>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <span class="disabled">&lt; Prev</span>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <!--truncated ...-->
```

With a pagination control similar to this you'll be able to pass any user set parameters back into the url. The first if() above the  is the really important part.

Comment: The above method of gaining access to the array of parameters passed to the partial works fine, as does unsetting the controller and action parameter. Thanks very much. I my case though I need the additional parameters (including page) to be represented as a query string. I have accepted your'e answer because it works. I will be including my complete partial below as an unaccepted answer because I think it deserves inclusion, but I want tt you to be credited. Thanks very much

Comment: As an aside, I'd like to know why *"The first if() above the is the really important part"*. Are you referring to the choice of whether to display the pagination controls on the basis of at least 1 row of data being present? Or is there something else?

Comment: Actually it's what's done after if($this->pageCount), where the current url is collected. $params gathers in everything passed in the url string including any user set parameters.

Comment: you just build a query string different then I do. I tend to rely on the ZF defaults and you pass a a standard query string. It all depends on what kind of routing you use

Comment: Yes, i wanted to use ZF urls with no *standard* query string, but the filtration paramaters come from a form, and the GET method always builds a *standard* qury string, so I'm just playing along.

Comment: so why use GET? I don't mean to be snide. I don't understand enough of what you are doing to be more helpful.

Comment: Well, really I want the url to reflect the choice of filter parameters when submitted. If I POST the filter parameters I won't get that. What I meant to say really was that I was using GET for that reason and given that, I have to accept using a query string (unless I want to do some redirecting in the controller). This is the situation as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this:

```
$params = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();
```

All you need is the query array:

```
$array = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getQuery();
```

this will save you having to unset variables as you will get a nice array containing only the query string :)